# vtk render with distancewidget inside a PyQT application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, vtk

the following simple code does not work and I just want to use `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` with `vtkDistanceWidget` to measure sphere length with mouse. but `vtkDistanceWidget` does not work

```
import sys
import vtk
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()

        self.vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        widget = vtk.vtkDistanceWidget()
        widget.SetInteractor(self.iren)
        widget.CreateDefaultRepresentation()
        widget.On()

        # Create source
        source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        source.SetRadius(5.0)

        # Create a mapper
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an actor
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()

        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can reproduce from here this functional example: https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Widgets/DistanceWidget ... BTW, I don't know Python, but I guess is not too hard to reproduce this in your language ...

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can implement this example because it's not in PyQt. could you please give another sample which implements vtkDistanceWidget in PyQt and QMainWindow ?

Comment: And here, a complete set of Python examples: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/

Comment: A Python example to angle widget (similar) could found here: https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/vtk/-/vtkAngleWidget/python-vtkanglewidget-function-examples.html

Comment: Thank you so much  @flaviu2  .  I got the answer .Good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed above, I got the answer by initializing `Interactor` inside main and moving self.show() after initializing.